# Capitalization of "Theorem 1" in mathematics papers

Tags: capitalization

In many mathematics papers, I read sentences like:

> With an appeal to Theorem 4.5 we get …

Is the capitalization of *theorem* in this case correct? If it is correct why do we capitalize the word?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized)

Comment: @Robusto: closely related, IMHO, but not actually a duplicate.

Comment: @Rhodri: Yeah, you're proably right. I took the term *title* in a broader sense.

Comment: This would seem better answered by people at [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com). Even though the question is about English usage, it is localized to their particular culture.

Comment: @Mitch: it's relevant to more than just maths textbooks.  Consider how it applies to Figure 3 or Table B.1

Comment: @Rhodri: sure it's relevant, but I read the question with 'and so on' as 'Lemma', 'Proposition', 'Definition' rather than 'Figure', Table'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is a matter of style. There's no reason internal references to theorems shouldn't be treated the same way as chapters. The grammatical reason for capitalizing them would be that they are [specific designators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun#Specific_designators), but it's somewhat of a judgment call as to whether they are. Here, Google Ngrams come in very handy. If you look at whether people capitalize *Chapter 3,* they usually do:

[image]

And they capitalize *Theorem 3* a slightly higher percentage of the time.

[image]

Google Ngrams also shows that very few people would capitalize *page 3.*

Comment: I would have expected a bigger change about the time TeX was introduced - perhaps journals used to edit/retype papers more.

Comment: I wonder what this actually shows. To me this only shows that "Theorem" is more often used than "theorem" but not that "Theorem" is the correct usage.

Comment: @Jonas T: If usage doesn't define what's correct for this question, what does?

Comment: @Martin: I expect the use of TeX caught on gradually, between 1980 and 1990. There's a fairly steep upward slope in the use of the capitalized *Theorem* during that period, which may correspond to this.

Comment: @Peter: Okay, maybe I don't know how the rules in English are made but to me saying that it is correct because more people use it is an ad populum fallacy.

Comment: @Jonas: I certainly agree with you about the *ad populum fallacy* applied to some aspects of English. But I don't see what rules you're going to use to decide this. See the [Specific Designators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun#Specific_designators) section of the Proper Nouns Page of Wikipedia. Is Theorem 3.5 a specific designator or not? It's a judgment call. Usage says that Theorem 3.5 is a specific designator but page 89 is not. I think this is reasonable. If you want to write your mathematics papers using lowercase *theorem 3.5,* that's between you and the editor.

Answer (score 9):

Theorem 4.5 is the *title* of the item in your book.  You would refer to it in the same way that you would refer to a chapter or section of the book, or the name of another book, by reproducing the same capitalization as the title's original appearance.

It looks unusual because we are used to making other references *within the same book* by chapter *number* (or page *number*, or whatever), rather than by title.  This is purely a matter of convenience; you have a general idea of where "chapter two" is where you'd probably have to look up "Elliptical Integrals".  It just happens that in this case the title contains a number.

Comment: Very nice answer. Indeed, we capitalize Table 4.3 because it's a title. You can see this with Google Ngrams, by checking that 'See Table' is [much more common](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=See+table%2CSee+Table&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than 'See table' (usually part of a construction like *See Table 4.3*); while 'See Table on' is [much less common](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=See+table+on%2CSee+Table+on+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than 'See table on' (usually part of a construction like *See table on page 77*).

Comment: I don't really understand this answer. If I write "Theorem 4.5." I would capitalize it because it is the first word in "sentence". This is the original appearance of the title, what am I missing?

Comment: @Peter: thank you very much for the links; I'm afraid I've never learned how to work Google Ngrams, but it is a good tool for showing this particular distinction!

Comment: @Jonas: sorry, I don't think I was very clear in my haste.  By "original appearance" I meant where it occurs, not what it looks like.  Think of it as the title of the sub(sub(sub...))section in which the theorem itself appears.  Unfortunately I don't have time to rewrite the answer properly at the moment, since my downloads are all finished and I need to get on with some work!  I'll see if I can put something better together this evening.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, it is correct to capitalize Theorem 4.5. The reason is because the Theorem 4.5 is actually the name of the theorem.

The rule for capitalization is to capitalize proper names, so names of theorems need to be capitalize.

Comment: Why are things like "Theorem 4.5" and so on proper nouns? They are not the same throughout all texts. It is not something like "Pythagoras' Theorem" which is the same througout all texts.

Comment: I must disagree with this answer. One does not say "Go to Page 5." Since it's a simple enumeration, "theorem 1" is really an abbreviation for "the first theorem" or "the theorem [which is] numbered 1."

Comment: @Jonas: "London" (or "George") is not less of a proper noun simply because there are multiple possible referents.